# My app's bottom bar (UITabBar) sometimes pushed halfway out of screen when personal hotspot (tethering) is enabled

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout

I am using autolayout on my app, I'm on latest iOS (8.1.3) but when I run my app with personal hotspot (or at any occasion where an extra bar is displayed on top) my app's tab bar *sometimes* gets halfway pushed down. If I take the app to background and back to foreground it resizes again correctly. It's very hard to reproduce the exact cause as it happens once and without changing anything, on next run, it doesn't.

What would be the cause of it? I'm pretty good with autolayout, how it works, and I have no layout ambiguities etc in my storyboard.

Comment: any luck? how to do that? finding same question but didn't get answer.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani I haven't implemented a solution to that app, but listening to the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and force a layout pass would be nice.

Comment: Yes i did same. when we get statusbar height `40` then force layout to be changed. and it worked. default height would be 20 and when hotspot is working then height would be 40.